# Сохранение в xml файл данных из datagrid

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте. Помогите, пожалуста, с сохранением в xml файл данных из datagrid, Поделитесь, пожалуйста, примером.

Comment: [первая ссылка в гугле](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/58a18dwa.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var persons=new List<Person>
    {
        new Person() {Age = 25, Name = "Bob"},
        new Person() {Age = 21, Name = "Steve"}
    };
    dataGridView1.DataSource = persons;
}

private void SerializeSettings()
{
    if (dataGridView1.DataSource==null ) return;
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Person>));
    var writer = new StreamWriter("config.xml");
    serializer.Serialize(writer, dataGridView1.DataSource as List<Person>);
    writer.Close();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    SerializeSettings();
}
```

Класс объектов которые отображаются в гриде и сериализуются

```
   [Serializable]
    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: получается вот такой xml 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfPerson xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Person>
    <Name>Bob</Name>
    <Age>25</Age>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <Name>Steve</Name>
    <Age>21</Age>
  </Person>
</ArrayOfPerson>